# Just to clear the air once and for all, how exactly do you update npm packages in your working repository?

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

Apologies if this is a basic question, I 'somewhat' know how to do it but at the same time do not and have scoured the internet for answers and none of the solutions seem to work.

Specifically, I am asking in regards to when github tells you that you have a security alert and must update a dependency in your package-lock file. How exactly do you solve this in your working repository? I am trying to simply update the necessary packages in my React.js repository and then push the package-lock file onto the master branch but cannot figure out a simple quick solution to do this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I always use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `npm update <package> --save`, that will update to the newest version and save that version to your package.json

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update.html